# ASP.NET Profile/Trace Framework

Tags: asp.net, profiling, trace

I'm looking for a ASP.NET module that will benchmark results, session, sql queries & other stuff & spit out on the page.  I know Trace will give you some of that but not the sql part.  I know Jeff had something similar for alpha stackoverflow, just wondering if there was a http module already out there that did this.

Similar to CodeIgniter profile class =  The Profiler Class will display benchmark results, queries you have run, and $_POST data at the bottom of your pages. This information can be useful during development in order to help with debugging and optimization.

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/profiling.html

Answer (score 2):

EQATEC makes a pretty good (and free) [Profiler](http://www.eqatec.com/tools/profiler) and [Tracer](http://www.eqatec.com/tools/tracer).

See also: [Profiling ASP.NET websites with EQATEC Profiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/378617/profiling-asp-net-websites-with-eqatec-profiler)

Answer (score 0):

I commented on [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200566/code-instrumentation-on-an-asp-net-web-application/1233072#1233072) earlier today. It shows how I wrote some code to do the SQL monitoring.